# Need help using random numbers and modulos

Tags: java, for-loop, random, division, modulo

I'm trying to make a simple program that will display 20 random numbers between 1 and 100 and then print out which numbers are divisible by 3 and equivalent to 1%3 and 2%3. It seems to work just fine but I've noticed it only works with the very last number in the list. What am I missing to include all the numbers in the search for my math? Thank you in advance for any help I can get!

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Lab5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int repeat = 19;
    int n = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<=repeat;i++){
        n = rnd.nextInt(100)+1; 
        System.out.print(n+", ");

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

    if(n % 3 == 0){
        System.out.println("Numbers divisible by three: "+n+(", "));

    }else{
        System.out.println("Numbers divisible by three: NONE");

    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    if(n == 1 % 3){
        System.out.println("Numbers equivalent to one modulo three: "+n+(", "));

    }else{
        System.out.println("Numbers equivalent to one modulo three: NONE");
    }

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

    if(n == 2 % 3){
     System.out.println("Numbers equivalent to two modulo three: "+n+(", "));

    }else{
        System.out.println("Numbers equivalent to two modulo three: NONE");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You're executing 20 iterations of the `for` loop, calculating n in each. Then, after the for loop is terminated, you do the `if` blocks. You need to execute the math inside the for loop.

Comment: Or, store the numbers into an array (or collection) and then do the math on the values in the array.

Answer (score 2):

It is only printing the last number because the check if the number is divisible, etc is not in your `for` loop at the top. Simply copy and paste all of the code below it into your `for` loop and it should work as you intended.

You also have an error here: `if (n == 1 % 3)`, it is legal but will check if n is equal to the remainder of 1 / 3. I don't think that is what you wanted to achieve, so correct it like this: `if (n % 3 == 1)` as Ypnypn suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Your `n` is declared outside of the loop body, so its value will persist. However, since you are overwriting `n` in each loop iteration, only the last value of `n` will persist and will be used by other parts of the program.

As Ypnypn has said, correct your use of `modulo`, and as Arbiter and deanosaur have suggested, move the rest of the program logic inside the `for loop`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for modulus is `n % 3 == 2`. The current code `n == 2 % 3` means `n == 0`, since the order of operations in Java requires that modulus is evaluated before equality.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting all the output statements (`System.out.println()`) *outside* your loop, so it only outputs the last value.

Move your output statements so they are inside your loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int repeat = 19;
    int n = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[3]; // To hold how many numbers have modulo 0, 1 or 2
    for(int i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
        n = rnd.nextInt(100)+1; 
        System.out.print(n+", ");
        if(n % 3 == 0) 
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is divisible by 3");
        else 
            System.out.println("" + n + " modulo 3 = " + n % 3);

        numbers[n % 3]++;
    }
    System.out.println("Numbers divisible by 3: " + numbers[0]);
    System.out.println("Numbers with modulo 3 = 1: " + numbers[1]);
    System.out.println("Numbers with modulo 3 = 2: " + numbers[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well .. you did not calculate anything in the loop, so your print statements work the last value of n after you exited the loop.  Try something like

```
package com.example.modulo;
import java.util.Random;
public class Modulo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int repeat = 19;
    int n = 0;

    int[] nMod = new int[3];
    nMod[0] = 0;
    nMod[1] = 0;
    nMod[2] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
        n = rnd.nextInt(100) + 1;
        nMod[n%3] = nMod[n%3] + 1;
        System.out.print(n + " (" + n%3 + "), ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Numbers divisible by three: " + nMod[0] + (", "));
    System.out.println("Numbers equivalent to one modulo three: " + nMod[1] + (", "));
    System.out.println("Numbers equivalent to two modulo three: " + nMod[2] + (", "));
}
}
```

Comment: Why the extra modulo package?

Comment: This looks good, but there is something wrong in your math. I'm getting answers such as "2" for numbers that are divisible by 3 and still only getting one result per line.

Comment: Try modifying the print statement in the loop to see the modulo. See what that shows you